# Selecting same column with different where conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

This query returns the sum of "closed" daily sales for a particular salesperson within a particular date range:

```
 SELECT SUM(price) as closed_total
 FROM   dbo.Sales
 WHERE  salesperson_ID = @salesperson_ID
        AND date_ordered BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
        AND closed = 1
 GROUP BY date_ordered
```

The output looks like:

```
daily_total
200
150
325
120
(etc)
```

I'd like to modify the query to return one column for closed sales, and one column for all sales (same query, but without the 'closed = 1' condition), with output like this:

```
closed_total | all_total
200          | 275
150          | 150
325          | 500
120          | 280
(etc)
```

I've tried using UNION to combine the separate queries, like this:

```
 SELECT SUM(price) as closed_total
 FROM   dbo.Sales
 WHERE  salesperson_ID = @salesperson_ID
        AND date_ordered BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
        AND closed = 1
 GROUP BY date_ordered
UNION ALL
 SELECT SUM(price) as all_total
 FROM   dbo.Sales
 WHERE  salesperson_ID = @salesperson_ID
        AND date_ordered BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
 GROUP BY date_ordered
```

I thought this might do what I was looking for, but it puts both sums into a single column named 'closed_total'.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT SUM(price) as total, SUM(CASE WHEN closed = 1 THEN price ELSE 0 END) as closed_total
 FROM   dbo.Sales
 WHERE  salesperson_ID = @salesperson_ID
        AND date_ordered BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
 GROUP BY date_ordered
```